# SBS 2008 SP2 Backup - Volume Shadow Copy Operation Failed

Tags: backup, exchange-2007, windows-sbs-2008, vss

**Server Setup**
Exchange 2007 Version: 08.03.0192.001 (Rollup 4)
Windows Small Business Server 2008 SP2 (Rollup 5)
Exchange set up on D: drive (449 GB / 698 GB Free)
80 GB / 148 GB Free on OS drive.

**Issue**
Backup Failure (VSS related)

**Backup Software**
Windows Server Backup (ver 1.0)

**Simplified Error**
Creation of the shared protection point timed out.
Unknown error (0x81000101)

The flush and hold writes operation on volume C: timed out while waiting for a release writes command.

Volume Shadow Copy Warning: VSS spent 43 seconds trying to flush and hold the volume \?\Volume{b562a5dd-8246-11de-a75b-806e6f6e6963}.  This might cause problems when other volumes in the shadow-copy set timeout waiting for the release-writes phase, and it can cause  the shadow-copy creation to fail.  Trying again when disk activity is lower may solve this problem.

**What I've tried**

- Server Reboot.
- Updated Server and Exchange.
- ReConfigured Sharepoint (Helped resolve last vss error I encountered).
- registered VSS Dll's (Backups will sometimes work afterwards but VSS writers fail soon after).
- Tried Implementing Hotfix:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/956136
- Tried Implementing Hotfix: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/972135
- I left it for a few days and a few backups came through but then began to fail again.

**Detailed Information**

Log Name:      Application
Source:        VSS
Date:          16/11/2011 8:02:11 PM
Event ID:      12341
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SERVER.DOMAIN.local 
Description:

Volume Shadow Copy Warning: VSS spent 43 seconds trying to flush and hold the volume \?\Volume{b562a5dd-8246-11de-a75b-806e6f6e6963}.  This might cause problems when other volumes in the shadow-copy set timeout waiting for the release-writes phase, and it can cause  the shadow-copy creation to fail.  Trying again when disk activity is lower may solve this problem.

Operation:
   Executing Asynchronous Operation

Context:
   Current State: flush-and-hold writes
   Volume Name: \?\Volume{b562a5dd-8246-11de-a75b-806e6f6e6963}\
Event Xml:

  
    
    12341
    3
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    1651049
    Application
    SERVER.DOMAIN.local
    
  
  
    43
    \?\Volume{b562a5dd-8246-11de-a75b-806e6f6e6963}\

Operation:
   Executing Asynchronous Operation

Context:
   Current State: flush-and-hold writes
   Volume Name: \?\Volume{b562a5dd-8246-11de-a75b-806e6f6e6963}\

=================================================================================

Log Name:      System
Source:        volsnap
Date:          16/11/2011 8:02:11 PM
Event ID:      8
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      SERVER.DOMAIN.local
Description:

The flush and hold writes operation on volume C: timed out while waiting for a release writes command.
Event Xml:

  
    
    8
    2
    0
    0x80000000000000
    
    987135
    System
    SERVER.DOMAIN.local

==================================================================================

Log Name:      Application
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-Backup
Date:          16/11/2011 8:11:18 PM
Event ID:      521
Task Category: None
Level:         Error
Keywords:
User:          SYSTEM
Computer:      SERVER.DOMAIN.local
Description:

Backup started at '16/11/2011 9:00:35 AM' failed as Volume Shadow copy operation failed for backup volumes with following error code '2155348001'. Please rerun backup once issue is resolved.
Event Xml:

  
    
    521
    0
    2
    0
    0
    0x8000000000000000
    
    1651065
    
    
    Application
    SERVER.DOMAIN.local
    
  
  
    2011-11-16T09:00:35.446Z
    2155348001
    %%2155348001

==================================================================================

Writer name: 'FRS Writer'
   Writer Id: {d76f5a28-3092-4589-ba48-2958fb88ce29}
   Writer Instance Id: {ba047fc6-9ce8-44ba-b59f-f2f8c07708aa}
   **State: [5] Waiting for completion**
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'ASR Writer'
   Writer Id: {be000cbe-11fe-4426-9c58-531aa6355fc4}
   Writer Instance Id: {0aace3e2-c840-4572-bf49-7fcc3fbcf56d}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Shadow Copy Optimization Writer'
   Writer Id: {4dc3bdd4-ab48-4d07-adb0-3bee2926fd7f}
   Writer Instance Id: {054593e2-2086-4480-92e5-30386509ed1b}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Registry Writer'
   Writer Id: {afbab4a2-367d-4d15-a586-71dbb18f8485}
   Writer Instance Id: {840e6f5f-f35a-4b65-bb20-060cf2ee892a}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'COM+ REGDB Writer'
   Writer Id: {542da469-d3e1-473c-9f4f-7847f01fc64f}
   Writer Instance Id: {9486bedc-f6e8-424b-b563-8b849d51b1e1}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'BITS Writer'
   Writer Id: {4969d978-be47-48b0-b100-f328f07ac1e0}
   Writer Instance Id: {29368bb3-e04b-4404-8fc9-e62dae18da91}
   State: [1] Stable
   Last error: No error

Writer name: 'Dhcp Jet Writer'
   Writer Id: {be9ac81e-3619-421f-920f-4c6fea9e93ad}
   Writer Instance Id: {cfb58c78-9609-4133-8fc8-f66b0d25e12d}
   **State: [5] Waiting for completion**
   Last error: No error

==================================================================================

Answer (score 1):

I ran the following in an elevated Command Prompt and this resolved it (if needed script it to run before each backup)

```
Takeown /f %windir%\winsxs\temp\PendingRenames /a 
icacls %windir%\winsxs\temp\PendingRenames /grant "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX)"
icacls %windir%\winsxs\temp\PendingRenames /grant "NT Service\trustedinstaller:(F)"
icacls %windir%\winsxs\temp\PendingRenames /grant BUILTIN\Users:(RX)
Takeown /f %windir%\winsxs\filemaps\* /a 
icacls %windir%\winsxs\filemaps\*.* /grant "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(RX)"
icacls %windir%\winsxs\filemaps\*.* /grant "NT Service\trustedinstaller:(F)"
icacls %windir%\winsxs\filemaps\*.* /grant BUILTIN\Users:(RX)

net stop cryptsvc
net start cryptsvc
```